# Unable to write to Excel file, getting OpenXML4JRuntimeException

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am attempting to read test data from excel and update the same sheet with the test result. Problem is that on the second iteration Eclipse IDE generates an exception and the status is not updated in excel either. Also the file appears to be damaged. Here is the code:

```
File src = new File("C:\\Users\\Sajid\\Desktop\\SeleniumData.xlsx");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(src, true);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++)
{
    // Import data for Email.
    cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"email\"]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"email\"]")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());

    String message = "Pass";
    sheet.getRow(i).createCell(15).setCellValue(message);
    workbook.write(fos);
}
```

The Exception:

> org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package: The part /docProps/app.xml failed to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@2e62e227

**Updated Code**

```
File src = new File("C:\\Users\\Sajid\\Desktop\\SeleniumData.xlsx");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(src, true);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++)
{
    // Import data for Email.
    cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

    String message = "Pass";
    sheet.getRow(i).createCell(15).setCellValue(message);
    workbook.write(fos);

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("b.hidden-xs")).click();
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.sign-out")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

fos.close();
fis.close();
```

However i am getting the null pointer exception for the **cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);** line

java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You can check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810214/org-apache-poi-openxml4j-exceptions-openxml4jruntimeexception-fail-to-save

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with Selenium. You should simplify your code down to an [mcve] (and only one) and repost your question. All the extra Selenium code, etc. that has nothing to do with the error is a distraction. My guess is that if you do something simple, it will fail also and then we can find the real issue. If I were to guess, you are using the wrong cell type. Try `cell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)` instead of what you have as the line that is failing.

Comment: thanks, will try tht

Answer (score 5):

One cannot at the same time open a file for input and output if it is not a random access file.

Also then the output should not append to an existing file, but rather replace the file.

Also write the workbook once.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
fis.close();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(src); // Without append true.
...
workbook.write(fos);
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

did you take a lool at this post [OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810214/org-apache-poi-openxml4j-exceptions-openxml4jruntimeexception-fail-to-save/34995753) ?

there are two solutions explained that might help you :

1- You are opening the file multiple times so before opening a file, check if it is closed.

2- The version of your jar file is getting override so add the dependency in your pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
<artifactId>batik-dom</artifactId>
<version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I did go through that post but couldn't quite get the solution. anyways thank you @hamza

Comment: Tried many options, code is updated. However i am still getting exception, this time the dreaded nullpointerexception.