# Getting an error when trying to insert data back into excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read in a text file, and then apply some data validations rules on it. After adding the rules I then write data back onto an excel file.

But when trying to write it back to the excel file I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to
>   save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part
>   /docProps/app.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@74ad1f1f
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:479)
>     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1414)
>     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:179)     at
>   com.gbt.POC.TxtFileReader.main(TxtFileReader.java:359) Caused by:
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException: The part
>   /docProps/app.xml fail to be saved in the stream with marshaller
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.DefaultMarshaller@74ad1f1f
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:470)
>     ... 3 more

Here is what I have so far:

```
LinkedList < String[] > llist = new LinkedList < > ();

String[] data;

XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream("data.xls");
XSSFSheet spreadSheet = workBook.createSheet("Clean");

for (int i = 0; i < llist.size(); i++) {
 if (i == 0) {
  System.out.println("Hello World!");
 } else {
  data = llist.get(i);

  String empid1 = data[0];
  String fname = data[1];
  String ccode1 = data[2];

  if (data[2].equals("IND")) {
   replace = data[2].replaceAll("IND", "IN");
   ccode1 = replace;
  } else if (data[2].equals("USA")) {
   replace = data[2].replaceAll("USA", "US");
   ccode1 = replace;
  } else {
   ccode1 = data[2];
  }

  //String newData=empid1+","+fname+","+ccode1;

  XSSFRow row = spreadSheet.createRow(i);

  XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue(empid1);

  cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue(fname);

  cell = row.createCell(2);
  cell.setCellValue(ccode1);
 }
}

workBook.write(outstream);
```

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code to see what error is it.
Unfortunately I couldn't see your error.
But after searching the error I found some answers..

> This exception occurred because the POI API for excel sheet writes to
>   the excel sheet multiple times. And each time it requires a new
>   instance of FileOutputStream over same File object.
>
> To resolve this, wrote all Rows to the workbook instance first, and at
>   one did write to the workbook using FileOutputStream.

https://tjavadeeps.wordpress.com/2015/04/14/org-apache-poi-openxml4j-exceptions-openxml4jruntimeexception-fail-to-save-an-error-occurs-while-saving-the-package/

[org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810214/org-apache-poi-openxml4j-exceptions-openxml4jruntimeexception-fail-to-save)

Hope you get a hint.

Next,
I made my txt file and save to excel like what you did and 
It works,

```
package excelTest;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class readExcel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LinkedList<String> llist = new LinkedList<>();
        String[] data = null;
        String replace = "";
        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream( "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data.xls");
        XSSFSheet spreadSheet = workBook.createSheet("Clean");

        /*
         * MyFile.txt
           ----------------------
            0
            IND 
            USA
            LOVE
           ----------------------
         */



        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\myFile.txt"))) {
            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                llist.add(sCurrentLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String empid1 = "";
        String fname = "";
        String ccode1 = "";


        System.out.println("llist.get(i)"+llist.get(0)+"   "+llist.get(1));
        for (int i = 0; i < llist.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(llist.get(i));
        }
        empid1 = llist.get(1);  //IND
        fname = llist.get(2);   //USA
        ccode1 =llist.get(3);   //LOVE


        if (fname.equals("IND")) {
            replace = fname.replaceAll("IND", "IN");
            ccode1 = replace;
        } else if (fname.equals("USA")) {
            replace = fname.replaceAll("USA", "US");
            ccode1 = replace; //'LOVE' CHANGE TO US. (IF YOU WANT TO CHANGE TO US IN HERE-> fname=fname.replaceAll("USA","US");
        } else {
            ccode1 = fname; //'LOVE' CHANGE TO USA AGAIN.
        }


        XSSFRow row = spreadSheet.createRow(0);

        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(empid1);

        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue(fname);

        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue(ccode1);
        workBook.write(outstream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [Xcelite library](http://xcelite.io) to make your life easier:

1. First create a little bean class
2. Create a Xcelite object and have it create a sheet
3. Get a Writer
4. Write you beans
5. Write to OutputStream

#### Bean class

```
import com.ebay.xcelite.annotations.Column;

public class Entity {
    @Column
    String empid1;
    @Column
    String fname;
    @Column
    String ccode1;
}
```

#### Create a Xcelite object and have it create a Sheet and a Writer

```
Xcelite xcelite = new Xcelite();
XceliteSheet sheet = xcelite.createSheet("Clean");
SheetWriter writer = sheet.getBeanWriter(Entity.class);
```

#### Write out

```
    writer.write(entities);
    xcelite.write(outstream);
```

To sum it up, here is your modified code:

```
    LinkedList<String[]> llist = new LinkedList <> ();
    String in0[] = new String[3];
    llist.add(in0);
    String in1[] = new String[3];
    in1[0] = "1";
    in1[1] = "testtest";
    in1[2] = "IND";
    llist.add(in1);

    String[] data;
    FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream( "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data.xls");
    Xcelite xcelite = new Xcelite();
    XceliteSheet sheet = xcelite.createSheet("Clean");
    SheetWriter writer = sheet.getBeanWriter(Entity.class);
    List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < llist.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        } else {
            data = llist.get(i);
            String ccode1 = data[2];

            String replace;
            if (data[2].equals("IND")) {
                replace = data[2].replaceAll("IND", "IN");
                ccode1 = replace;
            } else if (data[2].equals("USA")) {
                replace = data[2].replaceAll("USA", "US");
                ccode1 = replace;
            } else {
                ccode1 = data[2];
            }
            Entity entity = new Entity();
            entities.add(entity);
            entity.empid1 = data[0];
            entity.fname = data[1];
            entity.ccode1 = ccode1;
        }
    }
    writer.write(entities);
    xcelite.write(outstream);
}
```