# org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save Could not load [org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLStream]

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm facing problem with export function to an excel template.

Anyone has same problem? Could you help?

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLStream]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:595)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1539)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:227)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810214/org-apache-poi-openxml4j-exceptions-openxml4jruntimeexception-fail-to-save)

Comment: _"Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already."_

Comment: @Thirumal: Not really, it works after restarting tomcat or re-deploy war package, but later (i'm not sure how long), it throws this exception.

Comment: The problem could be many requests to access to same excel template. This API is to use for: exporting data and fill to xlsx template